# Make iOS application compatible with iPhone6 and iPhone6+ sizes

Tags: ios, screen, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I have created an application in which I have used an .xib for layout. Currently I use two different .xibs, one for iPhone4 320*480 and one for iPhone5 320*568. I am not using auto layout.

Now iPhone6 and iPhone6+ are available, with two different sizes, 4.7 inch and 5.5 inch.

How can I make my app compatible with these sizes?

Comment: A single storyboard with auto layout is the best way.

Comment: @rmaddy Your solution is perfect but I already mention that it's previous code so I have used .xib files.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way is to download Xcode 6 GM (which was released today) and then run your app and see how it looks. You may not have to do anything at all as iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus will scale most older apps seamlessly. Reference: http://www.imore.com/all-13-million-ios-apps-will-instantly-scale-iphone-6-and-iphone-6-plus

I also tried this out myself on my app (designed for 4" screens) and it worked well in both  the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus in the simulator.

Comment: Why were you surprised? The app still thinks it is running on the 4" iPhone. The display is simply scaled but all of the sizes and coordinates are same as far as the app is concerned.

Comment: I had tried using the "Resizable iPhone" option before the GM release with the rumored sizes and it looked like dog poo. But, you're right -- when I think about it -- if it's just scaling everything up and the aspect ratio is the same it shouldn't matter if I had hardcoded values or not.

Comment: Hi @rmaddy , can you help me with the same issue. I need to upgrade my existing app to iPhone6 & iPhone6+. I tested on simulator for iPhone6 and iPhone6+, it works fine on simulator. So, do I need to change the storyboard here to support both devices?